# Disable logging system debug (configuration dump) when spring boot starts

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

It seems that by default, Spring Boot dumps the logging system configuration (e.g log4j's -Dlog4j.debug is set, same with logback), meaning every application starts with verbose and not super useful messages, while reading the configuration file itself:

```
16:03:08,167 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:03:08,167 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:03:08,309 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
16:03:08,309 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
16:03:08,309 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
...
...
```

Is there a way to disable that, without setting the system properties by hand ?

Comment: what about setting the logging level for `ch.qos.logback` to `ERROR`?

Comment: Doesn't work - it's logging before actually reading the configuration :)

Comment: Good point! I'll do a little digging and see if I can find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's producing that output to warn you about a problem with your configuration. You need to replace your `<layout>` with an equivalently configured `<encoder>`. The Logback documentation that was linked to in the warning message contains more information: http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder